# How to send data from react native to any user's computers via wire or bluetooth?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I want to create the iOS application that need to send the image from iOS app to user's computer. Then, I plan to connect between computer and iOS app via bluetooth or usb cable.But,I have just learned react-native, I don't know the detail of react-native deeply. Has react native the function to do that for connecting with bluetooth or cable. 
I'm very thankful for all recommendations. Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called react-native-ble-plx or react-native-ble-plx-hive.
Both of these packages can be used with low energy blue tooth devices.

**For react-native-ble-plx**

iOS (pure react-native)

npm install --save react-native-ble-plx

react-native link react-native-ble-plx

Add empty Swift file if you don't have at least one:
Select File/New/File...

Choose Swift file and click Next.

Name it however you want, select your targets and create it.

Accept to create Objective-C bridging header.
Minimal supported version of iOS is 8.0

If you want to support background mode:
In your application target go to Capabilities tab and enable Uses Bluetooth LE Accessories in Background Modes section.

Pass restoreStateIdentifier and restoreStateFunction to BleManager constructor.

iOS (expo/Podfile)

Make sure your Expo project is detached.

npm install --save react-native-ble-plx

react-native link react-native-ble-plx

Add empty Swift file if you don't have at least one:

Select File/New/File...

Choose Swift file and click Next.

Name it however you want, select your application target and create it.

Accept to create Objective-C bridging header.

Update your ios/Podfile to contain:

pod 'react-native-ble-plx', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-ble-plx'
pod 'react-native-ble-plx-swift', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-ble-plx'

Enter ios folder and run pod update

Minimal supported version of iOS is 8.0

If you want to support background mode:

In your application target go to Capabilities tab and enable Uses Bluetooth LE 
Accessories in Background Modes section.

Pass restoreStateIdentifier and restoreStateFunction to BleManager constructor.

**react-native-ble-plx-hive is a precompiled version of react-native-ble-plx to speedup yarn install**

Comment: Thank u so much, You save my life. I will try this one. :)